# Understanding trees in ANTLR

Tags: java, antlr

I'm trying to use Antlr for some text IDE-like functions -- specifically parsing a file to identify the points for code folding, and for applying syntax highlighting.

First question - is Antlr suitable for this requirement, or is it overkill?  This *could* be achieved using regex and/or a hand-rolled parser ... but it seems that Antlr is out there to do this work for me.

I've had a look through the ... and the excellent tutorial resource [here](http://jumbleagilemanuals.blogspot.com/2008/03/10-steps-to-beginning-to-parsing-with.html).

I've managed to get a Java grammar built (using the [standard grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list)), and get everything parsed neatly into a tree.  However, I'd have expected to see elements nested within the tree.  In actual fact, everything is a child of the very top element.

Eg.  Given:

```
package com.example
public class Foo {
   String myString = "Hello World"
   // etc
}
```

I'd have expected the tree node for Foo to be a child of the node for the package declaration.  Likewise, myString would be a child of Foo.

Instead, I'm finding that `Foo` and `myString` (and everything else for that matter) are all children of `package`.

Here's the relevant excerpt doing the parsing:

```
public void init() throws Exception {
    CharStream c = new ANTLRFileStream(
            "src/com/inversion/parser/antlr/Test.code");

    Lexer lexer = new JavaLexer(c);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(tokens);
    parser.setTreeAdaptor(adaptor);

    compilationUnit_return result = parser.compilationUnit();
}

static final TreeAdaptor adaptor = new CommonTreeAdaptor() {
    public Object create(Token payload) {
        if (payload != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Create " + JavaParser.tokenNames[payload.getType()] + ":  L" + payload.getLine() + ":C" + payload.getCharPositionInLine() + " " + payload.getText());
        }
        return new CommonTree(payload);
    }
};
```

Examining `result.getTree()` returns a `CommonTree` instance, whose children are the result of the parsing.

**Expected value (perhaps incorrectly)**

```
package com.example (4 tokens)
   |
   +-- public class Foo (3 tokens)
        |
        +--- String myString = "Hello World" (4 tokens)
        +--- Comment "// etc"
```

(or something similar)

**Actual value** (All values are children of the root node of `result.getTree()` )

```
package
com
.
example
public
class
Foo
String
myString
=
"Hello World"
```

Is my understanding of how this should be working correct?

I'm a complete noob at Antlr so far, and I'm finding the learning curve quite steep.

Comment: Can you show the tree as you find it, and the tree as you would have expected it?

Comment: By the way, parsing non-regular languages can NOT be achieved with regular expressions.  Whenever you see "tree", "recursive", or "nested", think "no regex".

Comment: @Svante - Sure - I've expanded the expected vs actual in the post.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Yo Marty. I've used ANTLR to make a syntax colorizer in an IDE, so I can vouch that it is possible. If it helps, here's the source for it: http://code.google.com/p/pen-ui/source/browse/trunk/slippy/src/org/six11/slippy/SlippyStyledDocumentColorizer.java. If you poke around in that tree and in ../olive/ it might help.

(It's for a silly language of my own)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Java-6 grammar at the top of the file sharing section on [antlr.org](http://antlr.org/grammar/list) does not include tree building.  You'll need to do two things.  First, tell ANTLR you want to build an AST:

```
options {
    output=AST;
}
```

Second, you need to tell it what the tree should look like by either using the tree operators or by using the rewrite rules.  See the [documentation on tree construction](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction).  I usually end up doing a combination of both.

Answer (score 1):

To build tree, you should set output=AST.  (Abstract syntax tree)

As far as I know, in an ANTLR only 1 token can be the root of a tree, so you can't get exactly what you're looking for, but you can get close.

Check out:
http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction